# Parse migration "No reachable servers" on AWS EC2

Tags: mongodb, parsing, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration

I have one EC2 server on AWS. We have configured MongoDB (3.0.9):

- comment "bindIp" line in /etc/mongod.conf
- open 27017 port
- create an user dedicated to Parse migration.

I can connect to the database with Node.JS script (MongoClient) but when I click on Migrate in Parse website => **"No reachable servers"**.

Have you any idea ?
Thx

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with mLab and had to delete the "ssl" option on the connection string to make it work